# synonyms for "you're welcome"

Tags: phrase-choice, sentence-choice

Which one of the following (or maybe another one that you know) is the strongest answer for someone that sent me a lot of thanks and hearts for a favor that I did to him?

Obviously, I know the answer "you are welcome" but it seems to me too casual or banal and I'm looking for something else if there is such.

In the meantime, thanks to thesaurus.com ([here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/you're%20welcome)), I found the following options:

- Forget it
- Don't mention it
- It's nothing
- My pleasure
- No problem
- No worries
- Not at all
- You are welcome

Comment: You could write a full sentence using whatever you did for the person.

Comment: All of these options except perhaps "My pleasure" are significantly *more* casual than "You're welcome." I agree with @Lambie about using a full sentence; sometimes the time taken to say something is worth as much as the particular words used. For example, "You're very welcome. It was a pleasure to [do whatever you did] for you."

Comment: @Lambie Unfortunately I don't understand what you mean by "You could write a full sentence". Can you explain please?:)

Comment: @LukeSawczak In the bottom line you said that I have to consider with the option of "my pleasure" as stronger option and not casual one? If you did, then the problem with "my pleasure" is, If I'm not mistaken, in the past I have been told that this phrase is considered as arrogant or something like that. Is that true?:)

Comment: @VersatileandAffordable It's certainly not stronger — I just can't decide whether it's at the same level as "You're welcome" or more casual. As for arrogance, at least here in Canada I don't think anyone would be offended by "My pleasure." (It might be more pretentious if you said something like "The pleasure is all mine.")

Comment: John, I appreciate your thanking me for the favor but I cannot imagine not having done it as your participation [in whatever] is invaluable to all of us. [There's an example of a full sentence]. My pleasure is not arrogant in English.

Comment: The strongest way? Perhaps *I thank you from the bottom of my heart.* But I wouldn't say it if I didn't mean it.

Answer (score 4):

We often say things like *I'm glad I was able to help* to strengthen a formulaic response like the ones you listed. So you could say one of these:

> You are (very/most) welcome. I'm (very) glad I was able to help.
>   It was (my/a) pleasure. I'm (very) glad I was able to help.

In this case I would avoid those statements which tend to trivialize what you did: *not at all, no worries, no problem, it was nothing*. Those tend also to convey that you didn't do anything that the person had reason to be grateful for. That's appropriate if you really feel that way, but if you feel that you really did do a person a favor, it's better to say that you were happy to do it.