# When to say "you're welcome"

Tags: word-choice

I always learned when somebody says "thank you", I should say "you're welcome".

Coming to the US, I hear "you're welcome" almost never.  Instead I hear:

- No problem
- You bet
- No worries

I understand these are all different ways to say "you're welcome".  Is there a reason to not say "you're welcome" instead?  Is "you're welcome" more formal?

Comment: See [Synonyms for you're welcome](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132130/synonyms-for-youre-welcome). In short, *you're welcome* is fine anytime. And it is preferable in any formal situation. But in informal situations, the synonyms are often used.

Answer (score 1):

All those "**No problem**", "**You bet**", "**No worries**" and etc. are synonyms of "**You're welcome**"  which is, as I think, more formal. *(see Clare's comment)*

I, myself, always say "**you're welcome**" because, in my opinion, it sounds very polite and kind and can apply to even strangers whereas the other options wouldn't flawlessly be applied to a stranger.

Comment: To add to this, it's because "you're welcome" is the absolutely most correct response (and the one taught in English as a foreign language), while the synonyms have varying degrees of informality. Basically, it's the one you can't go wrong with no matter the context. US culture on the whole tends to use less formal turns of phrase than the UK, so the variance is not surprising when considered culturally.